# how to use NOT EXISTS in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to find one column value is present in another table column value.

e.g

```
Product_Name(tb_new_purchase)
1.car
2.bus
3.truck 


Product_Name(tb_new_product_Name_id)
1.car
```

i need to select bus and truck

Here is my code

```
SELECT Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id )
```

But its not returning any values.where i made error? thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are already 5 answers here....but just to throw this out here, you can do this as a join and not a where exists.  Subqueries can really hinder performance and runtime.  In MSSQL, the runtimes should be about the same...is MySQL, this join syntax works far better.

```
Select a.product_name
from tb_new_purchase a
left join tb_new_product_Name_id b on a.product_name = b.product_name
where b.product_name is null
```

Using a left join here will produce a null in the b.product_name column whenever the product_name is not in the b table.  Where product_name is null operates as a filter all lines that have an entry in the 'b' table here.

Comment: When making statements like "subqueries can really hinder performance", you should either run the tests yourself or check with those who have.  Otherwise, you run the risk of propagating misinformation.  @AaronBertrand has run such tests, and he prefers the `not exists` form.  Read about it here:  http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `NOT IN` or pass the field into the `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
WHERE Product_Name NOT IN(SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id)
```

or

```
SELECT Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
                  WHERE tb_new_product_Name_id = tb_new_purchase.Product_Name  )
```

Comment: can you please tell how to write in trigger using inserted

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

`SELECT Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
WHERE Product_Name NOT IN(SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is checking *all* the product names in `tb_new_product_Name_id`.  If the table is not empty, then it passes the `where` clause.  I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT np.Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase np
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM tb_new_product_Name_id npni
                   WHERE np.Product_Name = npni.Product_Name
                  );
```

Comment: can you please tell how to write in trigger using inserted

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition to restrict the subquery. If you execute the query

```
SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
```

It always returns some record so NOT EXISTS is false. Try something like

```
SELECT Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Product_Name 
                     FROM tb_new_product_Name_id 
                    WHERE tb_new_purchase.id = tb_new_product_Name_id.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXCEPT` to achieve what you need like this:

```
SELECT  Product_Name
FROM tb_new_purchase
EXCEPT
SELECT Product_Name 
FROM tb_new_product_Name_id
```